# Encapsulating java.util.Properties access through accessor methods considered bad practice?

Tags: java, encapsulation, software-design

I am using `java.util.Properties` for a project I am working on. I have a class that manages a .properties file with a `Properties` instance, called `PropertiesManager`. This class manages the loading and saving of the .properties file from disc.

Now because I wanted to make sure that one could only access valid properties and that default values were used whenever a property is not in the file, I added getters and setters for each property of the file.

The Problem is that makes the class `PropertiesManager` very big. The getters and setters alone (with comments/blank lines) are 300 lines of code. So even if I transfer the loading/saving in another class (inheritance etc.) it is still way to big.

This is not the actual code but it gives you the idea:

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesManager {
    private Properties properties;

    public PropertiesManager() {
        // constructor
    }

    private void save() {
        // save in .properties file
    }

    private void load() {
        // load from .properties file
    }

    public String getPropertyName1() {
        return properties.getProperty("PropertyName1", "Property1DefaultValue");
    }

    // 28 more getters here

    public String getPropertyName30() {
        return properties.getProperty("PropertyName30", "Property30DefaultValue");
    }

    public void setPropertyName1(String value) {
        properties.setProperty("PropertyName1", value);
    }

    // 28 more more setters here

    public void setPropertyName30(String value) {
        properties.setProperty("PropertyName30", value);
    }
}
```

Is it considered bad practice to encapsulate your access to the Properties instance like this? Should I just use the Properties instance directly instead of using accessor methods? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just change it to have a single getter/setter using an enum:

```
public class PropertiesManager {
    ...
    public String getProperty(EnumProp enumProp) {
        return properties.getProperty(enumProp.getKey(), enumProp.getDefaultValue());
    }

    public void setProperty(EnumProp enumProp, String value) {
        properties.setProperty(enumProp.getKey(), value);
    }
}
```

With this enum:

```
public enum EnumProp {
    PROP_1("key", "defaultValue"),
    ...

    EnumProp(String key, String defaultValue){
        this.key = key;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jesus! Same idea, I was just too slow :(

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This solution fulfills all my requirements and is very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered bad practice to encapsulate your access to the
>   Properties instance like this? Should I just use the Properties
>   instance directly instead of using accessor methods? Is there another
>   solution?

It is rather cumbersome as solution.

I think that it would be more maintainable and readable if you use a property files that contains all defaults value for keys where a default value should be used if not provided.

The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to modify the code to change a default value. You have just to change the default property file that can be outside the packaging of your application.

In your `PropertiesManager`  wrapper class, provide a `public String getProperty(String key)` method analog to the `getProperty()` method of the `Properties` class and if the value is not provided in the effective  properties file, use the default properties file to return the default value if it exists in.

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
     String value= properties.getProperty(key);
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)){
           value= propertiesDefault.getProperty(key);
     }
    return value;
}
```

You can rely on the same logic for the `setProperty()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I think I will use the enum variant, which was proposed in the two other answers, because it makes sure only valid keys can be used as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

It *does* make sense to encapsulate the `Properties` instance. What you *would* like to expose is an instance of something that delegates to the underlying `Properties` instance. I suggest you enumerate all supported proerties to reduce the public interface of `PropertiesManager`:

```
public class PropertiesManager {
    public enum Property {
        SOMETHING("PropertyName1", "PropertyName1DefaultValue"),
        ANOTHER("PropertyNameX", "PropertyNameXDefaultValue"),
        …;

        public final String key;
        public final String defaultValue;

        Property(String key, String defaultValue) {
            this.key = key;
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }
    }

    private Properties properties;

    public PropertiesManager() {
    }

    private void save() {
        // save in .properties file
    }

    private void load() {
        // load from .properties file
    }

    public String get(Property property) {
        return properties.getProperty(property.key, property.defaultValue);
    }

    public void set(Property property, String value) {
        properties.setProperty(property.key, value);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply invoke `propertyManager.get(SOMETHING)` and so forth.

Comment: Also to you: Thanks for the great answer! This solution fulfills all my requirements and is very elegant!

Comment: No worries :) (filler, 15 chars)